# Why dio authenticated requests dont work?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use http package by passing bear token to the http request it works but not with Dio package. What I am doing wrong?

```
 Dio _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
      connectTimeout: 5000,
      receiveTimeout: 100000,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer$bearToken'
      }
     )
  );
```

```
FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

Future<String>get bearToken async{
  return await storage.read(key: 'key').then((value) => value.toString());
}
```

log :

```
I/flutter ( 4648): Dio error!
I/flutter ( 4648): STATUS: 401
I/flutter ( 4648): DATA: {status: failed, error: Unauthenticated, code: 401}
I/flutter ( 4648): HEADERS: connection: close
I/flutter ( 4648): x-powered-by: PHP/8.0.7
I/flutter ( 4648): cache-control: no-cache, private
I/flutter ( 4648): date: Wed, 11 Aug 2021 12:58:29 GMT
I/flutter ( 4648): access-control-allow-origin: *
I/flutter ( 4648): host: 10.0.2.2:8000
I/flutter ( 4648): content-type: application/json
```

Comment: You need to await the bearToken

Comment: Should I do it like this: 'Authorization': 'Bearer'+await bearToken?

Comment: Await and assign the value to a variable and then use that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, u get the token asynchronously, so u need to await the result and store it to a variable.

Like this `final token = await bearToken;`

Secondly, add the space before token value. `'Bearer $bearToken'`